# How do I execute functions in my ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, ropsten

How can I manage to execute functions from my ERC20 token created with remix solidity and deployed on the ropsten test network? I was able to import it to my metamask account but I want to perform actions with it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed it via remix, the easiest way is by looking at the left panel.
You'll see your deployed contract show up, and if you click on the small arrow, you'll be able to call all of the contracts functions.

Alternatively if the contract source code is verified, you can go to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ and look up your contract. Under 'write contract' you will also be able to interact with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you have deployed your token in Remix, you will see all functions of your contract in bottom of deploy tab where you copied your smart contract address, there in tick near the address to show all functions